# STM32L475VG Led Controll

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, mbed

I have been working on stm32l475vg board with mbed library and I want to control all 4 leds of the board. The problem is that mbed configure led3 and led4 to the same one. In the file PinNames.h the definitions are:

```
LED_RED = P0_25,
LED_GREEN = P0_3,
LED_BLUE = P1_1,

// mbed original LED naming
LED1 = LED_RED,
LED2 = LED_GREEN,
LED3 = LED_BLUE,
LED4 = LED_BLUE,
```

Does anyone know how I can control each of them separately?

Comment: If it's DISCO-L475VG-IOT01A, the blue and yellow LEDs are both connected to PC_9 pin and it is not possible to control them individually. You can download schematics and verify that. https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/b-l475e-iot01a.html

Comment: @KentaroOkuda Thank you. It seems to be the same board

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @KentaroOkuda said both of the leds are connected to PC_9 so it is not possible to control them individually